# PyMongo json_util.dumps overwrite ObjectId representation

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bson

`bson.json_util` provides functions to convert to either canonical or relaxed JSON format. However, both of them stick to the same representation of the ObjectId:

```
from PyMongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from bson import json_util
from bson.json_util import RELAXED_JSON_OPTIONS
from bson.json_util import CANONICAL_JSON_OPTIONS, DEFAULT_JSON_OPTIONS


db = MongoClient(URL)['DB_NAME']
mongo_query_result = db.collection.find_one({'_id': ObjectId('ID')}, 
                                                   {'_id': 1})

# returns {'_id': ObjectId('ID')}

print(json_util.dumps(mongo_query_result, json_options=RELAXED_JSON_OPTIONS))
print(json_util.dumps(mongo_query_result, json_options=CANONICAL_JSON_OPTIONS))
print(json_util.dumps(mongo_query_result, json_options=DEFAULT_JSON_OPTIONS))

# Results
{"_id": {"$oid": "ID"}}
{"_id": {"$oid": "ID"}}
{"_id": {"$oid": "ID"}}

# Desired Output
{"_id": "ID"}
```

The problem with that is it doesn't match the results I get in prod env. I am using `PyMongo` just to build test cases, the actual prod format is

```
{'_id': "ID", ..etc}
```

I looked a bit in the documentation over [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html#bson.json_util.RELAXED_JSON_OPTIONS), and here are the findings:

1. Both CANONICAL_JSON_OPTIONS and RELAXED_JSON_OPTIONS stick to the problematic representation, specs over [here](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/extended-json.rst).
2. I can't seem to overwrite it because `uuid_representation=PYTHON_LEGACY` and I cannot seem to find a way around it.

Is there something I am missing to convert `PyMongo` query result to:

```
{'_id' : 'ID', ..}
# not
{'_id' : {'$oid' : 'ID'}, ..}
```

I would hate to extend my code just to handle the different format of the test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a work around, I was able to accomplish the same result with `re` regular expressions:

```
import re

def remove_oid(string):
    while True:
        pattern = re.compile('{\s*"\$oid":\s*(\"[a-z0-9]{1,}\")\s*}')
        match = re.search(pattern, string)
        if match:
            string = string.replace(match.group(0), match.group(1))
        else:
            return string

string = json_dumps(mongo_query_result)
string = remove_oid(string)
```

This essentially replaces the CANONICAL_JSON to normalized one and remove the key-value to just a value.

Although this gets the job done, it is not ideal, since I am manipulating `JSON` as a string, and very much error prone, plus doesn't work in `Date` or other format.

Answer (score 3):

This is my way of doing it, using only the provided `json` library

```python
json.dumps(list(products.find({})), default=lambda o: str(o))
```